# How to include a new file js in a project cocos2d js?

Tags: javascript, cocos2d-x-js

I'm trying to include a new js file containing a new scene on a cocos2d js project, but every time try occurs the following error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: GameScene is not defined.

I included my file in jsList and in appList:

```
"jsList"        : ["src/game_scene.js"],
    "appFiles"      : ["src/game_scene.js"]
```

The code of my scene looks normal:

```
var GameScene = cc.Scene.extend({
    onEnter:function(){
        this._super();

        var gameLayer = new GameLayer();
        this.addChild(gameLayer);
    }
});
```

The code on app.js to call my scene looks good too:

```
var gameScene = new GameScene();
cc.Director.runScene(gameScene);
```

What should I do?

Answer (score -1):

I solved the problem. I included the file in "jsList" of "project.json".